# Односвязный список: вывод

Tags: c++, список

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std ;

struct Node{
   int value ;
   struct Node *next ; 
} ;

int main(){

    struct Node *first = NULL ; 
    struct Node *p ;
    int n ;

    for (;;) {
        cin >> n;

        if (!n){
             break;
        }

        p = new struct Node;
        p->value = n;
        p->next = first ;
        first = p;
    }

    p = first;
    while (p) {
        cout << p->value << " " ;
        p = p->next;
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Почему вывод задом наперед? Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (;;) {
    p = new struct Node;
    ...
    p->next = first;
    first = p;
}
```

Вы новому элементу назначаете следующим предыдущий записанный: p->next = *нода из предыдущей итерации*, таким образом у последнего в next окажется предпоследний, который будет ссылаться на предпредпоследнего и т.д.

Соответственно, надо присваивать новый элемент предыдущему сохраненному:

```
prev = NULL;
for (;;) {
    p = new struct Node;
    if (prev != NULL)
        prev->next = p;
    prev = p;
}
```

По большому счету поменялось только то, *чьему* next и что присваивается.

Comment: Условия выхода из цикла обхода в вашем варианте не учитываются?

Comment: @Free_ze оно и значение не выставляет. Наверное, это потому что ответ про совсем другое.

Comment: @Fike 
=D
 Ок, будь по-вашему...